# Switch primary color of outlook calendar event

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

In Outlook 365's calendar, it's easy to assign multiple categories to a single event. However, only one color shows as primary (the background color) and all other categories just show up as a dot of color on the side.

This would be reasonable, except that it's always the **last** category that's applied which dictates the background color.  The only way I've found to change this is to remove one of the other categories and then re-apply it.  If I then want to add yet another category, I need to repeat the process to ensure the primary color is the one I want.

[image: Three events with the same categories]

Is there any way to select which category/color provides the background color, without having to add and remove categories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Nope.

This has been an issue with *all* versions of Outlook.  You've found the only solution (workaround) that exists for this problem.

Comment: Well that's disappointing.

Comment: I had the exact same question, and I am also disappointed by the answer.